# Delete row from more than one sheet based on TEXT message box

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, row

looking to change this script to work on more than 1 sheet (sheet1, sheet2, sheet3) based on the input box. I was able to add the names to the sheets, by call each separately in the script and then performing the add based on text, but I can't figure out how to delete. This is the script I found on here  from Mogsdad that I'm hoping to make work.

```
function Deletename() {    
  var value_to_check =
    Browser.inputBox(
      "Enter First and Last Name to Delete",
      "",
      Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);

  var FIRST_COLUMN = 1

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var DATA_SHEET =
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                  .getActiveSheet();

  ss.toast("removing duplicates...", "", -1);

  var dataCopy1 = DATA_SHEET.getDataRange().getValues();
  var deleted_rows = 0;

  if (dataCopy1.length > 0) {
    var i = DATA_SHEET.getLastRow(); // start at bottom

    while (i > 0) {
      if (dataCopy1[i - 1][FIRST_COLUMN - 1] === value_to_check) {    
        ss.deleteRow(i);
        deleted_rows++;
      }
      i--;
    }
  }

  ss.toast("Done! " + deleted_rows + ' rows removed', "", 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Instead of retrieving the active sheet, loop through all sheets

- Currently, you define 
  `var DATA_SHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();`
- This will apply your request only to the active sheet
- Instead, you can retrieve all sheets of the spreadsheet with [ss.getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) and define inside of a loop each of the available sheets as `DATA_SHEET` in turn
- Run the rest of the code within the loop as before, jsut be careful with deleting rows:
- If you have more than one sheet, change `ss.deleteRow(i);` to `DATA_SHEET.deleteRow(i);` to delete the row within the sheet through which you currently loop, rather than the active one

**Sample:**

```
function Deletename() {    
  var value_to_check =
      Browser.inputBox(
        "Enter First and Last Name to Delete",
        "",
        Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);

  var FIRST_COLUMN = 1

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var a = 0; a < sheets.length; a++){
    var DATA_SHEET = sheets[a];

    ss.toast("removing duplicates...", "", -1);

    var dataCopy1 = DATA_SHEET.getDataRange().getValues();
    var deleted_rows = 0;

    if (dataCopy1.length > 0) {
      var i = DATA_SHEET.getLastRow(); // start at bottom

      while (i > 0) {
        if (dataCopy1[i - 1][FIRST_COLUMN - 1] == value_to_check) {    
          DATA_SHEET.deleteRow(i);
          deleted_rows++;
        }
        i--;
      }
    }
  }
  ss.toast("Done! " + deleted_rows + ' rows removed', "", 5);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, that works! The spreadsheet has about 10 sheets and I just want it to just run on 3 of them. When I changed

var sheets = ss.getSheets();

to

var sheet = ss.getSheets()[2]; 
its says SS is not defined. For adding a name I went through each sheet like this:

  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[2];
    sheet.insertRowBefore(4);
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[3];
    sheet.insertRowBefore(4);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
    sheet.insertRowBefore(4);

again, thank you so much for you help. This has been driving me crazy for weeks.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that the first sheet would be `var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; `? Do you has a row 4 in all sheets you mentioned? Can you provide a sample sheet with the code that gives you trouble to have a look?

Comment: I made this example spreadsheet today, it is not the same sheet I am using but it will be the same idea. Thank you so much! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jdrv2ubsD7BU5sp8wJa-azs1ELfVcEhulqDrGH4thMY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I jsut tested the code as it is on the spreadsheet you provided and it worked correctly, not sure where your issue lies. If you want to use the function on only three adajcent sheets (lets say sheet 2, 3 and 4), you can query as `var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var a = 1; a < 4; a++){var DATA_SHEET = sheets[a];...`

Comment: Your script works great, thank you very much, I was more wondering about the specific sheets to be more careful with the deleting rows. I'm going to test the edit you just shared, but you first script worked great too.

Comment: If you want to be sure not to delete the rows on the wrong sheet, you can check for the sheet name before deleting. Sample:  `var sheets = ss.getSheets();  for (var a = 0; a < sheets.length; a++){  var DATA_SHEET = sheets[a]; if (DATA_SHEET.getName() == "X" || DATA_SHEET.getName() == "Y"){//paste here the rest of the code}`

Comment: That's perfect! I can use that for the add name script too, very helpful.Thank you